# c: rename file within kernel module

Tags: c, file, rename, kernel-module

I know how I can open/write/read a file within a loadable kernel module.

But is it also possible to rename/move a file? Maybe in the init-method?

Answer (score 1):

The `unlink()` system call (or its implementation inside the kernel) will remove a file.

The `link()` system call (or its implementation inside the kernel) can create a link to a file with a new name.  As long as you are renaming in a single file system, you can rename by doing `link()` to create the new name and `unlink()` to remove the old name.

The kernel does not support (so neither should your module support) renaming files across file systems.  That task is delegated to user commands like `mv`.